# Google Analytics Event Tracking code is not working

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I'm trying to implement Event Tracking to track clicks on banner links. The website is using Classic Google Analytics and I followed all the instructions provided by the Google. 
However the code is still not working and doesn't report any activity in GA.

```
<a href="http://www.playerauctions.com/runescape-gold/" onclick="_gaq.push([_'trackEvent','Banners','Internal link','Runescape gold: 100% safe trade of rs gold online',true]);"> <img title="Runescape gold: 100% safe trade of rs gold online" alt="Runescape gold: 100% safe trade of rs gold online" src="http://image.playerauctions.com/HomeBanner//Homepage_news_banner_20150114231011_298_Runescape_v2.jpg"></img></a>
```

I don't know what is wrong with the code.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A few comments: your value needs to be an integer. You are passing in 'true'. If that is supposed to be the non interaction flag, then you need to set the value to be 'undefined'. You won't see the event in your reports right away as it takes about 24 hours for data to be processed. You can check real time reports though for the event. You should also consider moving to Universal Analytics as Classic will no longer be supported.